# How to completely disable iTerm2 pop up messages

Tags: terminal, vim, python, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 on my Mac, build 3.1.3, and I am working with two tabs. One tab has my Python code in vim. The other one is where I actually run it with `python code_here.py`.

However, each time I edit in vim, save, and then switch tabs and run the same `python code_name.py` command, I constantly get this popup message:

```
Session IPython: Users/myname/ (vim) #1 just rang a bell!
```

How do I completely disable this popup? Actually, for that matter, I'd like to disable *all* such popup message from iTerm2.

Comment: Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal tab -> Check "Silence bell" ?

Comment: Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal tab -> Uncheck "Send Growl/Notification Center Alerts?"

Comment: Both of ^^^ are significantly more helpful to me personally than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Apple System Preferences -> Notifications
2. In the left list panel, scroll to find the entry for iTerm (or iTerm2).
3. In the right control panel, set iTerm alert style to None.

[image: Image: System notification settings for iTerm to disable vim notifications]